# Is SpeechKit framework supported in watchOS 3?

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-3, speechkit

I tried to import the SpeechKit framework for watchOS and received an error. Is there a way to use it with watch? I am getting an error when I import the Speechkit Framework saying "no such module Speech"

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import Speech

class SpeechInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}
```

}

Comment: Pl. Post your code and error what you get.

Comment: I have added the code and error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Speech framework is not in the watchOS SDK (as of watchOS 3.0-3.1, at least). You can see this [in the framework docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech):

[image: speech framework docs screenshot]

(If it supported watchOS, tvOS, or macOS, those would be listed under SDK on that page.)

You can also see the set of available frameworks in your Xcode SDK: look at `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/`, or at the jump bar atop the Xcode editor pane when you look at the ObjC version of a watchOS system header file, or the list of available options when you manually add to Linked Frameworks and Libraries for your project's WatchKit extension target.

Answer (score 2):

SpeechKit framework is not available for watchOS 3.

To get the speech recognition in a watch app you can instead use:

```
presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: nil, allowedInputMode: .plain) { (results) in
    if let results = results?.first as? String {
        self.label.setText(results)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, why -1 ?

Comment: I forgot about this option.  Thanks!  It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's helpful.